# What is .Net equivalent for Visual FoxPro Trace window while debugging

Tags: c#, debugging

I started coding in C# and debugging is smooth if my code *throws an error*. But I have a code where there is *no error* and I miss the FoxPro `Trace` window to see the execution line by line.
Is there something similar in .NET IDE?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use **F10** to execute the Program line by line. Also, you can put a breakpoint and when the program stops, use **F10** again.

I suggest you to search more information about **Visual Studio Debugger** on Google.